# How to hold the current Jenkins job execution until the dependency job completion in post build action

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have a scenario to trigger an another build in POST BUILD ACTION, and It will take 1m to complete and I just want to make the current build to wait until that dependency job complete (1m duration) and update the status (COMPLETED,FAILED,UNSTABLE).

It's like I have a job name called A and B. B is the dependency which needs to run in POST BUILD ACTION in JOB A. Once the JOB B completed the execution (1M duration) I want to publish the status of JOB A. JOB A needs to be hold until the JOB B execution complete in POST BUILD ACTION.

How can I achieve this? Any leads...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy if you don't restricted to do it only in **Post Build** section (e.g., when you need to trigger other build only if the main build is stable, but I think that with 1min job you just don't care about that).

You just need to install [Parameterized Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger) plugin and it will allow you to add `Trigger/call builds on other projects` section in your **Build** section (not in **Post Build**). And you need also to enable `Block until the triggered projects finish their builds` option to wait until your job B is finished and check the status of job B:
[image]

Comment: If you have a build queue with 1 stop this means both will be waiting for eachother.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a tricky problem to resolve as POST BUILD means that the job B will trigger AFTER job A is completed.

Something that you can try is to trigger the Job A and B in parallel and for the Job B you can add a build step to `Execute shell` with for example `sleep 5m`, so the Job B will sleep 5 minutes at the beginning and then it will run the actual job you want. In the Job A you can then have a shell script which will in loop read the console output of Job B and the loop will finish after the console of Job B will produce the output `Finished:` and then you can continue with the logic based on the job output.

For reading the console output, you can do something like this in a loop (and grep for the `Finished:` keyword):

`curl -u ${USERNAME}:${TOKEN} {JENKINS_URL}/job/{JOB_NAME}/lastBuild/consoleText | grep {what you need}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage the [PostBuildScript](https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuildscript/) plugin together with the [Parameterized Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger) plugin. PostBuildScript will give you a post-build step called Execute scripts, which will enable you to add a Parameterized Trigger build step in the post-build stage. Thus, you can configure that to wait for the triggered job's completion.